# For what ABIs I can build apk with NDK v10e?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, abi

Currently project are builded with NDK v10e for

```
armeabi-v7a x86
```

Is those ABIs are old? Are they x32 only?
Will I be able to build project to build for other modern ABIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 64-bit ABIs were added in r10:

> Android NDK, Revision 10 (July 2014)
>
> Important changes:
>   Added 3 new ABIs, all 64-bit: arm64-v8a, x86_64, mips64.

See [the NDK revision history](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history)

Comment: So, I am able to build for modern devices with NDK r10?

Comment: And I am curious of what difficulties I am gonna face using such an old version of NDK?

Comment: It will include a pretty old version of Clang and GCC, as well as old versions of the STL - so there may be features missing that you have in newer versions. There may also be bugs that have been fixed in later versions. It may not play nicely with Gradle, etc. Bottom line is: it's usually a pretty bad idea to stick with ancient software versions.

Comment: I would like to transfer it to current ver of NDK, but there are cons: c++ code builded by NDK are dependent on prebuilded libs. I have this libs prebuilded only for x86 ABI. When I am trying to make NDK build it, I have a lot of reprecated- or -undeclared stuff:
`error: use of undeclared identifier 'AV_CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED'; did you mean 'AV_CODEC_ID_TRUEHD'?`
`error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'char *' with an rvalue of type 'volatile char *'`

Comment: I think that's too difficult task to ask to help with in stackoverflow comments ... but thank you anyway for detailed answers! ) Now I understand the issue deeper

Comment: Keep in mind that Google Play no longer allow you to publish apps that contain only 32-bit native libraries.

Comment: Yea, and it will ban 32-bit from google play at all in 2022, if I am not mistaking.

Comment: Also, I tracked down all of JNI calls in project to only one cpp file. And I have all includes from that file. e.g. `#include <GLES/gl.h>` but I don't have GLES folder. Is that from web? From stl? How do I find this dependencie to include in my project with current ver of NDK?

Comment: The `GLES` folder will be in `platforms/android-NN/arch-XX/usr/include`